# How to redirect the visitors to another site in Middleman?

Tags: ruby, redirect, middleman

Redirecting to another site was **very** easy in PHP. If they wanted to redirect visitors from *"www.yoursite.com/news"* to *"www.bbc.com"*...all I had to do was make the "news" folder and create an index.php file in it and add this line:

```
<?php
   header("Location: http://www.bbc.com/");
?>
```

And I was done! But I recently started working on a project written in Ruby, and having trouble to figure out how to achieve this simple task :<

This might be a very silly question, but any help will be greatly appreciated!!

**UPDATE:**

So found out that this project is using static site generator Middleman to build the site, that's why there is no `routes.rb` file. It only has `config.rb`. Can anyone please help me to figure out how to redirect in middleman?

**2nd UPDATE:**

Looks like because of Middleman, this redirecting isn't possible that simply. So I am asking this (very dumb) question: [How to redirect URL in Javascript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28245518/1081016)

Comment: So are you using Ruby on Rails or Middleman? O_o

Comment: it's written in Ruby, and using Middleman static-site generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally found an easy solution to my problem :)

In order to redirect **www.yoursite.com/news** to **www.bbc.com**, first I created a `news.html.erb` file under my `source` folder (where you have your `index.html.erb` file). And in that file I added the following lines and wallaaahhhh!

```
<% content_for :body_content do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Javascript URL redirection
    window.location.replace("http://www.bbc.com/");
  </script>

  <noscript>
    // Using HTML refresh meta tag as a fail back in case the user has javascript disabled
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.bbc.com/">
  </noscript>
<% end %>
```

One thing I should mention here is that [most sites](http://www.yourhowto.net/how-to-redirect-url-in-javascript-or-jquery/) suggested

> using `window.location.href`, because `replace()` does not put the originating page in the session history, meaning the user won’t get stuck in a never-ending back-button process.

But in my case `window.location.href` wasn't doing the trick :(

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to setup a custom route in routes.rb:

```
get "/news" => redirect("http://bbc.com")
```

Comment: but how do i tell RoR to redirect only when the url is "www.yoursite.com/news"?

Comment: Thank you Thomas O, i think your modified answer is what i am looking for. Now I just have to figure out how come this project doesn't have the  routes.rb file :(

Comment: Yeah that is bizarre. Good luck!