# How to redirect URL in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

Can some one please help me to understand how to do this following PHP's simple redirection in either Javascript or jQuery?

If the client wanted to redirect the `www.clientsite.com/bbc` to `http://www.bbc.com/` then in PHP I would just make the "bbc" folder and create an `index.php` file in it and add these lines:

```
<?php
  header("Location: http://www.bbc.com/");
?>
```

So my question is, how can I redirect `www.clientsite.com/bbc` to `BBC` page, or if it's `www.clientsite.com/food` then to `Food Network` and so on with either Javascript or jQuery? Thank you very much in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Thank you everyone for your help! For some reason the `window.location.href` wasn't redirecting my page, so I ended up using the `window.location.replace`. And found these pages very helpful:

- http://www.yourhowto.net/how-to-redirect-url-in-javascript-or-jquery
- http://www.rapidtables.com/web/dev/javascript-redirect.htm

Comment: `window.location.href = 'http://www.bbc.com'`

Comment: Inspect the current contents of `window.location.href` before you update it.  Please don't use comments to expand on or ask new questions though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS redirect with nojs fallback.

Code:

```
<script>
  window.location.href = "YOUR-URL";
</script>

<noscript>
  <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=YOUR-URL">
</noscript>
```

Comment: thank you for providing the meat tag solution as well, wasn't thinking of what if the user has javascript disabled :)

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='http://wmtest2.nl/portfolio/'},19500);

19500 - is timing, this will redirect to the link after 19.5secs